не работает scanf в цикле vs code
писал код
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
short ar[10], marks[5];
size_t count = 0;
size_t sz_ar = sizeof(ar) / sizeof(*ar);
size_t sz_marks = sizeof(marks) / sizeof(*marks);

while(count < sz_ar && scanf("%hd", &ar[count]) == 1)
    count++;
for(int i=0;i<sz_marks;i++){
    if (marks[i]!=0)
        marks[i]=ar[sz_ar-i-1];
}
for(int i=0;i<sz_marks;i++)
    printf("%d ",marks[i]);

return 0;
}

столкнулся с проблемой - ввожу строку с значениями для scanf, нажимаю энтер, но программа не реагирует. остается поле ввода, поле вывода не появляется. как это исправить? помогите пожалуйста

Хм... https://onlinegdb.com/ooDzsVCLK как-то работает

чет у меня не работает. не понимаю

Для начала: вставьте printf (с \n) в цикл ввода данных. Что-нибудь печатает?

Ввожу к примеру:
5
4
3
2
1
2
3
4
5
6
Вывод: 6 5 4 3 2
Process finished with exit code 0 - все сработало.
В глаза бросается то что вы используете "%d" в printf. Должно быть также printf "%hd"

Обращение к неинициализированному объекту if (marks[i]!=0) является Неопределенным Поведением.
